# What can the JdbcTemplate return?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

In a spring test they ask,
which can be the return type of a jdbcTemplate query.

Option were, with 3x to choose:

- JSONObject
- Generic Map
- Domain Object
- String

Im pretty sure with String and Domain Object, but what is the third?

Comment: I would go with a [`Map<String, Object>`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7758ba3c7e4f21435ed927417eb3a13c37af5551/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L1223). Not sure about the *generic Map* term, though. So, adding as a comment.

Comment: Have you tried anything to find this out?

Answer (score 0):

It returns `Generic Type`, pretty much all.

```
@Override
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, @Nullable Object[] args, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException {
    return queryForObject(sql, args, getSingleColumnRowMapper(requiredType));
}
```

Map<String, Object>

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> queryForMap(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes) throws DataAccessException {
    return result(queryForObject(sql, args, argTypes, getColumnMapRowMapper()));
}
```